# Use limit range in yii2?

Tags: php, mysql, database, yii, yii2

I want to get data from db using **limit 12,20** .

Here is my code:

```
  $Query = new Query;
   $Query->select(['um.id as USERid', 'um.first_name', 'um.last_name',   'um.email', 'COUNT(g.id) as guestCount'])
 ->from('user_master um')
 ->join('LEFT JOIN', 'guest g', 'g.user_id = um.id')
 ->limit(12,20)
 ->groupBy('um.id')
 ->orderBy(['um.id' => SORT_DESC]);

  $command = $Query->createCommand();
  $evevtsUserDetail = $command->queryAll();
```

It is not working. It is giving me all rows. I also tried  **->limit([12,20])**, not working.

But when I am using  **limit(12)** then I am getting 12 rows.

I want to get rows in **limit 12,20** . What should I have to do for that in my this code?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try this:

```
$Query = new Query;
$Query->select(['um.id as USERid', 'um.first_name', 'um.last_name','um.email','COUNT(g.id) as guestCount'])
->from('user_master um')
->join('LEFT JOIN', 'guest g', 'g.user_id = um.id')
->limit(20)
->offset(12)
->groupBy('um.id')
->orderBy(['um.id' => SORT_DESC]);
```

`Offset()` specifies the starting point and `limit()` specifies the Number of records. If you want records between `12` and `20` then use `limit(8)`.

For More Info:

- http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/select-query-model/#offset
- http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-querytrait.html#offset%28%29-detail

Answer (score 4):

you can do with Active record

```
$model = YourModel::find()->where('user_id = :user_id', [':user_id' => \Yii::$app->user->id])->limit(12,20)->all();
```

OR

```
$model = YourModel::find()->where('user_id = :user_id', [':user_id' => \Yii::$app->user->id])->with(['job','job.jobRecipient'])->limit(12)->all();
```

Comment: your Model must be extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord