# How to change default Yii 2 Rest API GET response result

Tags: php, rest, yii

According to Yii 2 Rest APi documentation, I have a `CountriesCountry` that extends `\yii\rest\ActiveController` and a corresponding `Countries model`. This is the code for my Controller class.

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

class CountriesController extends \yii\rest\ActiveController{

public $modelClass = 'app\models\Countries';

public function actionIndex(){

}

public function actionView(){

}

public function actionCreate(){

}

public function actionUpdate(){

}

public function actionDelete(){

}

public function actionOptions(){

}

}
```

When I send a get request, it returns all the countries in my database.

**My Question**

is it possible to return my own result from action methods. Like in the `actionIndex()`, I will like to limit the result to 20 records. I did something like this but it is not working.

```
 public function actionIndex(){

    $model = Countries::find()->limit(20);
    print_r($model);
}
```

I know that I can get all the countries from by database and loop through it and obtain only 20 results but I want to just query for 20 records from database.

Comment: [Could you try limit() and offset()?](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html#limit-offset) [See this answer as an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32156285/3585500).

Comment: put limit with your api link and get that limit into controller and then  $model = Countries::find()->limit($_GET['limit]);

Answer (score 1):

Your class CountriesController that extends from \yii\rest\ActiveController automatically supports GET, PUT, POST calls etc. No need for actionIndex(), actionCreate(), etc if you just want regular REST functionality. Read about it in the [Yii2 guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html).

To limit the results you could just set another page size in your controllers afterAction-method. Add this to your controller. (I believe that 20 records is default of Pagination class, so if that is what you want you don't need this code at all. Just use the default functionality of yii/rest/ActiveController.)

```
public function afterAction($action, $result) {
    if (isset($result->pagination) && ($result->pagination !== false)) {
        $result->pagination->setPageSize(100);
    }
    return parent::afterAction($action, $result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your api link is:

```
http://localhost/yii2-rest/api/country/?limit=15&order=id
```

Controller:

```
 public function actionIndex(){
       $model = Countries::find()           
        ->orderBy($_GET['order'])
        ->limit($_GET['limit'])
        ->all();    
       return $model;
     }
```

Take care about security!

You can get query string this way:

```
$limit = Yii::app()->getRequest()->getQuery('limit');
```

Answer (score -3):

**Straightway**

```
//SELECT * FROM countries LIMIT 20
$countries= Countries::find()->limit(20)->all();
```

Comment: Scopes were removed in Yii2.