# yii2 find return only first five record

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Am using yii2 find() and would like to return only first five records

THIS IS what ive tried

```
 $items= \frontend\models\TblResearch::find()->orderBy("id")->all();
```

That returs all the records what am looking for is

```
 $items= \frontend\models\TblResearch::find()->orderBy("id")
        ->all(); //instead of all use like something to return five records
```

How do i go about this

I would like only to use the model approach not the sql

Comment: for more information and clarity you can goto http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32155900/use-limit-range-in-yii2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `limit()`

`$items= \frontend\models\TblResearch::find()->orderBy("id")->limit(5)->all();`